# ¿Por qué no funciona mi transición?

Tags: html, css, transition

Esto es algo muy simple. Quiero que al desplegar el div cuando hago click en el botón, se vea una ligera transición que haga que tarde 0.3 segundos en desplegarse. En otros casos me funciona pero en este no sé por qué no.

En mi DOM tengo lo siguiente:

```
 <section>
    <div class="section-experience"><h1>Experiencia</h1></div>
    <button onclick="ver('experience')">Ver experiencia</button>
    <div id="experience" class="experience">
      <p>Desarrollador</p>
      <p>Técnico programador</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="section-studies"><h1>Estudios</h1></div>
    <button onclick="ver('studies')">Ver estudios</button>
    <div id="studies" class="studies">
      <p>Técnico Superior</p>
      <p>Múltiples cursos en Udemy</p>
      <p>Bootcamp Desarrollo</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="section-experience"><h1>Idiomas</h1></div>
    <button onclick="ver('idiomas')">Ver Idiomas</button>
    <div id="idiomas" class="idiomas">
        <p>Español</p>
        <p>Inglés</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="section-experience"><h1>Actitudes</h1></div>
    <button onclick="ver('actitudes')">Ver Actitudes</button>
    <div id="actitudes" class="actitudes">
        <p>Resiliencia</p>
        <p>Resolutividad</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

En mi JS añado la clase active cuando hago click en el botón correspondiente:

```
function ver(arg) {
    if (arg === "studies") {
        var element = document.getElementById('studies');
        element.classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById('experience').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('idiomas').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('actitudes').classList.remove("active");
    } else if (arg === "experience") {
        var element = document.getElementById('experience');
        element.classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById('studies').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('idiomas').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('actitudes').classList.remove("active");
    } else if (arg === "actitudes") {
        var element = document.getElementById('actitudes');
        element.classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById('studies').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('idiomas').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('experience').classList.remove("active");
    } else if (arg === "idiomas") {
        var element = document.getElementById('idiomas');
        element.classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById('studies').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('experience').classList.remove("active");
        document.getElementById('actitudes').classList.remove("active");
    }
}
```

Y en el CSS tengo mi clase active:

```
.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: azure;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

He probado también a añadir estas transiciones a las clases .experience, .studies, .idiomas y .actitudes pero tampoco me funciona.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que la propiedad `display: block;` no puede animarse.

Lo que te recomiendo es que agregues un `visibility:hidden` y un `opacity:0` a los elementos ocultos, en lugar de `display:none`

Cuándo agregues la clase active cambias estos valores: `visibility:visible` y `opacity:1`

Entonces cuándo se muestren estos elementos, lo harán con una ligera transición.

Comment: Perfecto!! El problema era el display. Al final he tenido que usar visibility, height y opacity para que quede perfecto. Muchhas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Qué tal? Su clase .active usa `display:block` por lo que se entiende intenta ocultar el div con `display:none` y generar la animación, pero debido a que esta propiedad css no es animable puede usar `visibility`: `hidden` y `visible` y simular el display con el height del div de esta forma

**HTML**

```
<section >
    <div class="section-experience"><h1>Experiencia</h1></div>
    <button onclick="ver('experience')">Ver experiencia</button>
    <div id="experience" class="hidden">
      <p>Desarrollador</p>
      <p>Técnico programador</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;          
}
.active {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: azure;
    visibility: visible;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
function ver(arg) {
    if  (arg === "experience") {
        var element = document.getElementById('experience');
        element.classList.add('active') 
        //... 
        //...
    } 
    //else if ...  
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Efectivamente. Ese era el problema: el display. Muchísimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Editando solo el css:

```
.experience,
.studies,
.idiomas,
.actitudes {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
  background-color: azure;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```